# Magento- How to Check Custom Module developed in CE Will work in Enterprise Edition Or not?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Just Develop Custom Module In CE . how can i check it works in Enterprise Edition or not?

Answer (score 1):

All the differences you can found in the form of extra modules in "app/code/core/Enterprise", class names start with "Enterprise" instead of "Mage", some are encoded with ionCube. There is an "enterprise" theme too but it is very similar to "modern". The rest of Magento is the same as the Community Edition so your extension will likely work on both equally.

And you can also refer Already have [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151985/magento-community-vs-magento-enterprise-coding-wise) with good answer

let me know if you need any assist.

Answer (score 0):

same as CE. you can run your module using the url.
the url format is also same.

```
 ex: domain_name/index.php/module_route_name/controller_name/action_name
```

where module_route_name is what you define in the

```
<routers> tag of the modules etc/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a magento module. It works fine for community edition and enterprise edition in my local environment. After installed it in the live site it works fine for community edition, but not for enterprise edition. It is not showing any admin configuration in enterprise edition. Am I missing anything?